# One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

### Background

I have a website deployed in multiple machines. I want to create a Google Custom Metric that specifies the throughput of it - how many calls were served.

The idea was to create a custom metric that collects information about served requests and 1 time per minute to update the information into a custom metric. So, for each machine, this code can happen a maximum of 1-time per minute. But this process is happening on each machine on my cluster.

Running the code locally is working perfectly.

### The problem

> I'm getting this error: Grpc.Core.RpcException:
>   Status(StatusCode=InvalidArgument, Detail="One or more TimeSeries
>   could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently
>   than the maximum sampling period configured for the metric.  {Metric:
>   custom.googleapis.com/web/2xx, Timestamps: {Youngest Existing:
>   '2019/09/28-23:58:59.000', New: '2019/09/28-23:59:02.000'}}:
>   timeSeries[0]; One or more points were written more frequently than
>   the maximum sampling period configured for the metric. {Metric:
>   custom.googleapis.com/web/4xx, Timestamps: {Youngest Existing:
>   '2019/09/28-23:58:59.000', New: '2019/09/28-23:59:02.000'}}:
>   timeSeries[1](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas)")

Then, I was reading in the custom metric [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quotas) that:

```
Rate at which data can be written to a single time series = one point per minute
```

I was thinking that Google Cloud Custom Metric will handle the concurrencies issues for me.

According to their limitations, the only option for me to implement realtime monitoring is to put another application that will collect information from all machines and will update it into a custom metric. It sounds to me like too much work for a real use case.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Is the machine name is in the metric?

Comment: No, but I tried to add the machine name to the metric type now. Now I don't get the error but I also can't aggregate (SUM) the multiple metric types into one value. It looks like N different graphs (where N is the number of machines). How to combine them together (SUM)?

Comment: It would probably help if you posted the description of your Stackdriver dashboard visualization.  You should find an aggregation capability and what you likely want to do is select the SUM aggregation available there.

Comment: I think you're running into a issue with cardinality - try using machine name as the label.  You could also just write each value as a log and then use a log-based metric.

Comment: I am having the above issue with Cloud Run instances. There is no machine name or any kind of salt to add to the information. Lets hope that we find a fix for it.

Answer (score 1):

From reading through the documentation of micrometer and in our case cloud run custom metrics posted to stack driver i figured that we would need to set up resource labels and resource type unique per application/instance.

Its mentioned in the document here
*You can also configure resource labels with the StackdriverConfig method resourceLabels. Depending on the configured resourceType, there will be required resource labels. See the documentation on choosing a monitored resource type.*

***When using Micrometer across multiple applications/instances, it is necessary that Stackdriver labels are unique per application/instance. Otherwise, you will see errors like One or more TimeSeries could not be written: One or more points were written more frequently than the maximum sampling period configured. If using a resource type other than global, the resource labels may already make metrics unique per application instance. If not, a common tag with the hostname or platform-provided instance ID may be a good candidate for achieving this.***

https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/stackdriver

In our case we are running micronaut in cloud run and i had set the following props

```
public MeterRegistry meterRegistry(){
    StackdriverConfig stackdriverConfig = new StackdriverConfig() {
        @Override
        public String projectId() {
            return projectId;
        }

        @Override
        public String get(String key) {
            return null;
        }
        //setting for batching writes
        @Override
        public int batchSize(){
            return 1000;
        }
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> resourceLabels(){
            String uniq = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, true);
            final Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
             map.put("node_id", uniq);
             map.put("namespace", "my app-"+uniq);
             map.put("location", location);
             return map;
        }
        @Override
        public String resourceType(){
            return "generic_node";
        }
    };
```

ResourceType should be one of this https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_generic_node

Resource Labels should be with respect to type.

Available custom metrics services

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/creating-metrics#which-resource

Answer (score 0):

Now that you add the machine name on the metric and you get the machines metrics.

To SUM these metrics go to Stackdriver > Metric Explorer, and group your metrics  by project-id or label for example, and then SUM the metrics.

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/charts/metrics-selector#alignment

You can save the chart in a custom dashboard.